# Anyone know the identity of this set?

Tags: set-identification

Came in a single unnumbered bag with standard 2011 markings.

[image: set pieces]

Answer (score 4):

Based on the Tan [Window 1 x 2 x 2 2/3 with Rounded Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30044&idColor=2#T=C&C=2)
and the 4 Red [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 x 1 1/3 with Curved Top](http://LegoBrick,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20x%201%201/3%20with%20Curved%20Top)

This is from [10696-1: Medium Creative Brick Box](https://brickset.com/sets/10696-1/Medium-Creative-Brick-Box)

[image]